# VBA: Find last days of month and copy to another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

i am completely new to VBA in Excel and trying to learn as much as I can as fast as I can so it can help me with my master thesis.

I have a fairly large dataset consisting of daily stock returns. I would like to copy the last day of each month into a new sheet but I am stuck in doing so.

Currently I am using a code to generate a column of dates based on column A in a different worksheet. I have provided this code below but it does not actually filter, it just generates the first and 15th day of the next month.

```
Private Sub Listmonths(strWksResult As String, strWksData As String)

Dim FirstDate As Date
Dim LastDate As Date
Dim NextDate As Date

FirstDate = Worksheets(strWksData).Range("A21").Value
LastDate = Worksheets(strWksData).Range("A4696").Value

NextDate = FirstDate
Worksheets(strWksResult).Range("A2").Select
'selection of columns within one row
Do Until NextDate >= LastDate

ActiveCell.Value = NextDate
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

If Day(NextDate) = 1 Then
    NextDate = DateAdd("d", NextDate, 14)
Else
    NextDate = DateAdd("d", NextDate, 20)
    NextDate = DateSerial(Year(NextDate), Month(NextDate), 1)
End If

Loop


End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Look into [WorksheetFunction.EoMonth](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197615.aspx)

Comment: As you're new to VBA, a piece of general advice: only use `.Select` if you reeeaally have to, and only for the purpose of setting a cell to be selected for the benefit of the user. In the code, just directly reference the appropriate `Range` or `Worksheet` etc.

Comment: Thank you, I will certainly keep that in mind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace these lines:

```
If Day(NextDate) = 1 Then
    NextDate = DateAdd("d", NextDate, 14)
Else
    NextDate = DateAdd("d", NextDate, 20)
    NextDate = DateSerial(Year(NextDate), Month(NextDate), 1)
End If
```

with

```
Select Case Day(NextDate)
Case 1
    NextDate = NextDate + 14
Case 15
    NextDate = DateSerial(Year(NextDate), Month(NextDate) + 1, 1) - 1
Case Else
    NextDate = DateSerial(Year(NextDate), Month(NextDate) + 1, 1)
End Select
```

To get (1) the first day of each month, (2) the 15th of each month, and (3) the last day of each month.

If you are merely looking for the last day of each month then you should only use

```
NextDate = DateSerial(Year(NextDate), Month(NextDate) + 2, 1) - 1
```

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for your quick answer!

Secondly, after replacing the lines you said, it still generates the first and 15th day of each month but it also generates the last day of each month. How can I make sure that it only gives the last day of each month?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood you the first time. I thought you wanted the 1st, 15th, and last day of each month. I just updated the solution according to your comment.

Comment: Again, thank you for you quick respons. When I only use the NextDate line whether by itself or as a part of  'Select Case', it generates an infinite number of the same date. After several adjustments I just cannot manage to show the last dates in that column. How would I incorporate your line in my code to make it work? 
Again, my apologies if this is something obvious, I am still learning.

Comment: Ups, sorry, yes, my bad. It should be `NextDate = DateSerial(Year(NextDate), Month(NextDate) + 2, 1) - 1` (as I have corrected it now).

Comment: Thank you very much for your assistance!

Answer (score 0):

The last day of each month is one day before the first day of the next month. This way it's easy to write either VBA code or an Excel Formula.

If the original date is d, then

```
DateSerial(Year(d), Month(d) + 1, 1) - 1
```

is the last day of the month that contains d.

**Update**

I didn't know which part of the problem is obvious to you. Here is a full version of the code (it found it better to build it from scratch):

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Listmonths(strWksResult As String, strWksData As String)
    Dim rngResult As Range: Set rngResult = Worksheets(strWksResult).Range("A1")
    Dim rngDates As Range: Set rngDates = Worksheets(strWksData).Range("A21:A4696") ' This should be changed to a Named Range or calculation based on UsedRange
    Dim rr As Long: rr = 1
    Dim r As Long: For r = 1 To rngDates.Rows.Count
        Dim varDate As Variant: varDate = rngDates.Cells(r, 1).Value ' In case of performance problems read the whole range at once
        If IsDate(varDate) Then
            If varDate = DateSerial(Year(varDate), Month(varDate) + 1, 1) - 1 Then
                rngResult.Cells(rr, 1).Value = varDate
                rngResult.Cells(rr, 2).Value = rngDates.Cells(r, 2).Value ' In case of performance problems write the whole range at once
                rr = rr + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: This may seem like an obvious question but how would I incorporate this in my code so that only the last day of each month is copied?